# how to add xml file when u have drawable-hdpi,mdpi,ldpi instead of drawable in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add XML drawable in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966065/how-to-add-xml-drawable-in-eclipse)

Ok guys I'm little stacked here. According to official documentation Google says that "Once you've defined your Drawable in XML, save the file in the res/drawable/ directory of your project." is the way to add a XML drawable to the project.
But when I created the project ADT created 3 different drawable folders for mdpi, hdpi, and ldpi. So when I wanted to create my XML drawable, I right click on my drawable-hdpi folder and select "Add new Android XML file", and there I have to select what kind of XML file I want to create, but there isn't "drawable" to select.
If I create new text file and save it as button_drawable.xml Eclipse says that there is an Error in the file and that It can't build my project.
So, please tell me how do you add xml drawables in Eclipse